# SQL Nested CASE - shortcut logic?

Tags: sql, logic, case, shortcut

I am trying to get rid of all of my dynamic SQL code.  This stored procedure seems to require some nested CASE statements withing the WHERE clause.  This is working as expected. However, I am worried about the performance.  Will the nested ( GuarantorNumber not in ( select... ) ) statements be executed if the parent CASE statements are not true?

```
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN ( @method='ADDED_RECORDS' ) THEN
      CASE WHEN 
        ( pt.[GuarantorNumber] not in (select cpg.GuarantorNumber from [CorepointProtectedGuarantor] cpg) ) THEN
          1
          ELSE 0 END -- NEW_RECORDS

       WHEN ( @method='DELETED_RECORDS' ) THEN
      CASE WHEN 
        ( pt.[GuarantorNumber] not in (select mpg.GuarantorNumber from [MeditechProtectedGuarantor] mpg) ) THEN
          1
          ELSE 0 END -- DELETED_RECORDS

       WHEN ( @method='UPDATED_RECORDS' ) THEN
      CASE WHEN 
        ( pt.[GuarantorNumber] in 
            (SELECT mpg.GuarantorNumber FROM 
                  [MeditechProtectedGuarantor] mpg, 
                  [CorepointProtectedGuarantor] cpg 
            WHERE 
                  mpg.GuarantorNumber = cpg.GuarantorNumber and
                  (mpg.[LastName] <> cpg.[LastName] OR 
                        mpg.[FirstName] <> cpg.[FirstName] OR 
                        mpg.[MiddleName] <> cpg.[MiddleName] OR 
                        mpg.[Address] <> cpg.[Address] OR 
                        mpg.[AddressLine2] <> cpg.[AddressLine2] OR 
                        mpg.[City] <> cpg.[City] OR 
                        mpg.[State] <> cpg.[State] OR 
                        mpg.[ZIP] <> cpg.[ZIP] OR 
                        mpg.[Phone] <> cpg.[Phone])

            ) -- end of SELECT clause
            ) -- end of WHEN clause 
            THEN
          1
          ELSE 0 END -- UPDATED_RECORDS
```

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Searched CASE expression:

- Returns the result_expression of the first input_expression = when_expression that evaluates to TRUE.

In your case if @method='ADDED_RECORDS' and @method='DELETED_RECORDS' are false then the next statement will be executed WHEN(@method='UPDATED_RECORDS') In SQLServer2008 to analysе this behavior symply by pressing Cntl+L.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @query nvarchar(max) 

Declare @selectoneCount int

Declare @Temp int

SET @Temp =1

Declare @val nvarchar(max)

SET @val =''

select 
       @query = case @Temp

       when 1 

       then       
          case @val

          when 'NULL'

          then
            ('Select Diameter from BallsProbes where Remark =2') 

          else
            ('Select Diameter from BallsProbes where Remark =3')   
            END 
       when 2 
       then ('Select Diameter from BallsProbes where Remark =6')
       end

EXEC(@query)
```